# Find the polynomial: $x P(x-1)=(x+1)P(x)$

Tags: polynomials

Find all polynomials $P(x) \in \mathbb R\left[x\right]$, satisfying:
$$xP(x-1) = (x+1)P(x)$$

I tried, but I am getting something like this:
$$P(x)=\ldots(x-3)(x-2)(x-1)(x)(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)\ldots$$
(My teacher gave me this math question and I need help because my answer is not looking like a polynomial)

Comment: What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you.

Comment: It would also be in your best interest to write the math in your questions using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Many users in this forum won't even read your question if it's not properly formatted, let alone help you.

Comment: I am getting P(x)=...........(x-3)(x-2)(x-1)(x)(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)...........

Comment: @ady An infinite product of linear factors is not a polynomial. But you should [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4712815/edit) that into the question, as well as how you derived that form, rather than posting it as a comment.

Comment: Hint. You didn't write how you arrive to that, but you're probably using without noticing that $p(x)$ is not the $0$ polynomial.

Comment: Let $Q(x)=xP(x-1)$. Then, the question is equivalent to asking whether $Q(x)=Q(x+1)$.

Answer (score 3):

One can easily see that zero polynomial satisfies the given condition $xp(x-1)=(x+1)p(x)$.

Now suppose $p(x)$ is a non-trivial polynomial then substituting $x+1$ in place of $x$ in the above constraint gives $(x+1)p(x)=(x+2)p(x+1)$. Thus, moving inductively, one can see that $xp(x-1)=(x+n)p(x+n-1)$  holds for each $n$. Since, $p(x)$ is a polynomial, the right hand side of the above equation tends to $\pm\infty$ as $n$ becomes larger and larger, which is absurd because $xp(x-1)$ is supposed to be a fixed quantity. Thus, a non-trivial polynomial cannot satisfy the given constraint.

Comment: That works (+1), or you could argue that setting $x=0$ in the sequence of equalities implies $p(0)=0=p(1)=p(2)=\ldots$ but a non-zero polynomial can only have finitely many roots.

Comment: @dxiv You argument is even more lucid, I should have noticed that.

Comment: @dxiv ... Or by setting $Q(x):=(x-1)P(x)$ giving $Q(x)=Q(x+1)$ which means that $Q$ is periodical with period $1$, which is impossible for a non-zero polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $P(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ is a polynomial.  Then $Q(x) = (x+1)P(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ is a polynomial such that $$Q(x-1) = ((x-1)+1)P(x-1) = xP(x-1) = (x+1)P(x) = Q(x)$$
for every $x$ and therefore $Q(x) - Q(0)$ has a zero at every integer-value of $x$.  The only way a polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ can have infinitely many zeros is if it's the zero polynomial, so $Q(x) - Q(0) = 0,$ or $$Q(0) = Q(x) = (x+1)P(x).$$

Setting $x=-1$ implies $Q(0) = 0$ so $(x+1)P(x) = 0$, or $P(x) = 0$ is the zero polynomial.